# not printing inside celery task

Tags: python, flask, celery

In my celery I tried printing inside a task, but I cant seem to output the data even in console.

Here is my structure:

```
/app.py
@app.route('//create', methods = ['POST'])
def create_file():
request.form .......
callback = build_file.s(name, address)
header = [ send_param.s( id, key ) for key in request_api.keys() ]
result = chord(header)(callback)

@celery.task(name='app.send_param', routing_key='send_param', queue='send_param', retry=False, bind=True)
def send_param(seld, id, key):
    //do something
    print 'NOT WORKING'

@celery.task(name='app.build_file', routing_key='send_param', queue='send_param', retry=False, bind=True)
def build_file(seld, name, address):
    //do something
    print 'NOT WORKING'
```

When printing within my create_file function it does print, but within my tasks it doesnt.

Answer (score 0):

The most straightforward solution will be to:

1) Configure a Logger instance which will capture all output from `logger.info()` (and other log levels) and put it into a local file or just `stdout`

2) While configuring, set

```
app.conf.update(CELERYD_HIJACK_ROOT_LOGGER=False)
```

to prevent Celery from removing any previously configured Loggers (more info: http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/configuration.html#logging).

---

Another option could be using the Siglans: http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/signals.html

but it is a little bit more involved and probably an overkill in your situation.